# Mat expansion panel extend over other html elements

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-material-6

I have a mat expansion panel that I would like to extend over the element below it rather than simply moving that element down. I tried adjust the z-index of the mat-expansion element but that did not work. I haven't seen anything in the angular material docs/github that suggests this can be done. Has anyone done this or know how this could be achieved?

Any help/tips/suggestions would be much appreciated.

[image: my expansion]

**UPDATE:** 
my desired solution should look similar to this. It could contain several elements (mat-selection, date picker, etc..)

[image]

Comment: Did you considered adding custom classes and CSS declarations or overwriting them?

Comment: Why are you using mat expansion panel for something so small? Just create your own element. Expansion panel is designed to work as an accordion. And accordion does push stuff down :)

Comment: Or rather use mat menu

Comment: Just use a div, show it when needed with *ngIf, you can animate it also. Tell me if you need help I can provide an example

Comment: @wFitz what animation pieces would be need to get the same expand as the mat-expansion?

Comment: Please see : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rb5vmu the last example "Animated Div" should give you a starting point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Big thanks to @wixFitz for getting me going in the right direction but here is the end product.
[image]

**animation.html:**

```html
<div class="report-filter">
  <button 
    mat-raised-button 
    class="filter-button"
    type="button"
    click)="showDiv()"
    ngClass]="{'menu-button-active': filterActive}">
    'TOOLTIP.filter' | translate }}
    <mat-icon>filter_list</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <div [@divState]="divState" class="menu mat-elevation-z8">
    <button
      class="center"
      mat-button
      click)="closeMe()"
      mat-icon-button>
      <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <div class="search-brands">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select placeholder="Brands" [(value)]="selectedBrand" panelClass="brandSelectDropdown">
          <mat-option (click)="resetBrand()" value="">none</mat-option>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let brand of brands" (click)="setBrand(brand.brand)" value="brand.brand">{{ brand.brand }}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**animation.scss:**

```css
.report-filter {
  display: flex;
  .filter-button {
    margin: 1rem 0;
  }
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 248px;
  right: 23px;
  background-color: $grey600;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 2;
  .search-brands {
    margin: 2rem 1rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: $grey300;
    mat-form-field {
      width: 95%;
      margin: 0rem 0.5rem;
    }
  }
  button {
    mat-icon {
      color: white;
      margin: 0 0 0 0;
    }
  }
}
.menu-button-active {
  background-color: $grey600;
  color: white;
}
```

**animation.ts:**
*In @Component object*

```js
animations: [
  trigger('divState', [
    state('show', style({ height: '100vh', width: '20vw' })),
    state('hide', style({ height: '0vh', display: 'none'})),
    transition('show => hide', animate('200ms ease-out')),
    transition('hide => show', animate('300ms ease-in'))
  ])
]
```

*global var*

```js
divState: string = "hide";
```

*open and close functions*

```js
showDiv() {
  this.divState = (this.divState == 'hide') ? 'show' : 'hide';
  this.filterActive = !this.filterActive
  this.getBrands();
}
  
closeMe() {
  this.divState = 'hide';
  this.filterActive = !this.filterActive
}
```

Comment: This code gives a warning when opening the overlay and skips the animation. The close animation works though. The warning: `The animation trigger "divState" is attempting to animate the following not animatable properties: display`

Comment: Fix for the above: `state('hide', style({ height: '0vh', visibility: 'hidden' }))`

Answer (score 0):

The above solution mentioned by @Brian Stanley is really complicated. Apply css styles and add FlexLayoutModule as mentioned in the below link. I have tried it and my expansion panel overlays perfectly.

[Panel Overlay Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hdmfut?file=package.json)